# Is there a reason why you can't use the pop() method by element/value name in lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

Python beginner just wondering why is it you're not able to pop() an item from a list by using it's value within a list, instead having to know it's index?

e.g.

```
colours = ["blue", "purple"]
colour_1 = colours.pop(0)
print(colour_1)
```

Why could I not instead write

```
colour_1 = colours.pop("blue")
```

Maybe a dumb question, but I was curious about this and I'm pretty new, thanks :)

Comment: You are looking for `list.remove`

Comment: Because pop() takes an index (position) as its argument.

Comment: It should be obvious that a single list method can't handle both remove-by-position and remove-by-value - how would it know which to do, in cases where the value is also a valid position number?

Comment: Well, @jasonharper gave you the answer, but if you only want to use ```pop()``` method, you can delete element by value like ```colour_1 = colours.pop(colours.index("blue"))```

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me why you wouldn't be able to write it as, for example. ' pop(0) ' for removing by index and something like ' pop("blue") ' for removing by value, the quotation marks being the differentiation between it knowing if you were searching by index or by value @jasonharper

Comment: Thanks @Sajid and I know about the remove() method which you can use to remove by value, but you can't also store the deleted value into a variable like you can with pop() can you?